# Python interpreter that should not exist shown in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm a linux user (zorin-os distro) using the flatpak version of Visual Studio Code.
I have downloaded the necessary extensions (Python and Pylance).

I have selected my interpreter but there is something bothering me.

[image]

As you can see I have 4 interpreters available but firstly, my version of python is 3.8.10 and NOT 3.10.11 and secondly, the 2nd and 4th interpreter does not work because the file does not exist.
Another thing, if I type `which python` in the shell then the result is `usr/bin/python` but here the recommanded interpreter is `bin/python`.

My questions are:

1. Why are there interpreters that do not exist? Can I remove them?
2. Why the version mismatch? Do I have to configure something?
3. Why is the recommanded interpreter not the same as the one used by my os? Is there any difference?

Comment: you can try uninstalling all the Python interpreters. and reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved on its own.
I don't know how but I may have an idea.

As I said in my conversation with @JialeDu (see above), my python vscode interpreters are located at `/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/22.08/ac3b29f9b04246d2b346de5632914232ee9c511702fc3c4e0d1c125a6de1e3ca/files/bin` and the folder "22.08" make me think that it needed ubuntu-22 to function properly (which wasn't present in zorin-os before version 16.3).

So if it happens that you're using the distro zorin, maybe updating to the last version available will solve your problem.

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there interpreters who does not exist ? Can i remove them ?

There are duplicate or wrong interpreters due to caching etc, usually restarting vscode or refreshing the **Select Interpreter** panel will remove them.

> Why the version mismatch ? Do I have to configure something ?

No, the interpreter you choose in the **Select Interpreter** panel is the one used by the ***Python*** extension.

> Why the recommanded interpreter is not the same as the one used by my os ? Is there any difference ?

[This explains where the extension will look for interpreters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) and [how it will recommend an interpreter for the current workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_how-the-extension-chooses-an-environment-automatically).

*The interpreter selected in vscode is only valid for **Python** extensions. But there may be multiple python environments throughout the operating system, and the preferred interpreter will be related to your environment variable `path`.*

Comment: Thanks ! restarting vscode or refreshing didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure those paths don't exist? Can you show user and workspace settings.json files?

Comment: I don't know how but the problem is no more, all 4 interpreters now work completely fine.
I have no idea how but the vscode python interpreter is located in "/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/22.08/ac3b29f9b04246d2b346de5632914232ee9c511702fc3c4e0d1c125a6de1e3ca/files/bin" and the folder "22.08" make me think that it needed ubuntu-22 (which wasn't present before zorin-os 16.3)
Anyway, thanks !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)